# How to echo results by sets of 2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

How do I modify an SQL result set so that the **result is (A)** and not (B). I need to somehow break the loop for every 2 results so that those two results get wrapped around a row class. Please see below:

(A) What I like to happen:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-6 columns"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns"></div>
  <div class="large-6 columns"></div>
</div>
```

(B) What happens:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-6 columns"></div>
   <div class="large-6 columns"></div>   
   <div class="large-6 columns"></div>
   <div class="large-6 columns"></div>
</div>
```

CODE:

```
<div class="row"> 

<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM recipe";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>         

  <div class="large-6 columns">          

     <h4><?php echo $row['recipe_title'] ?></h4>

     <p><?php echo $row['recipe_description'] ?></p> 

  </div> 

<?php } ?>

</div>
```

Comment: How is formed your db table? How you want those record to be split?

Comment: This could be achieved using the `modulus` operator for every iteration of 2 (ie, `rowCount++ % 2 == 0`)

Comment: Basically, I have a recipe table with 2 columns (recipe title, recipe_description) for simplicity. Currently, it holds 4 records. I want to split them into groups of 2 to be wrapped around a row class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add a counter variable, which is increased everytime the loop is called. Use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) then to close the current row and open a new one after the loop was called twice:

```
<div class="row"> 

<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM recipe";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>         

  <div class="large-6 columns">          

     <h4><?php echo $row['recipe_title'] ?></h4>

     <p><?php echo $row['recipe_description'] ?></p> 

  </div> 

<?php 
    if($i % 2 === 0) {
        echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }
    $i++;
} 

?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickest/dirtiest:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc(...)) {
   $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc(...);
   ... output $row1 data
   ... output $row2 data
}
```

This will work fine if you only ever get an even number of rows in the result set. Otherwise, the inner fetch will fail on the very last row because the while() fetch consumed the last result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM recipe";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$i = 0
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($i % 2 === 0) {
  echo '<div class="row">';
} 
?>         

  <div class="large-6 columns">          
     <h4><?php echo $row['recipe_title'] ?></h4>
     <p><?php echo $row['recipe_description'] ?></p> 
  </div> 

<?php
if ($i % 2 === 0) {
  echo '</div>';
}
$i += 1;
?>         

<?php } ?>
</div>
```